# Sqlite Subsonic C#: Guid is saving as Guid with SQL, but with strange characters when using code

Tags: c#, sqlite, subsonic

I am using System.Data.SQLite with an sqlCommand String, this saves a Guid as expected.

Using code I strange Characters save instead of Guid as follows: ù“•»I={E±gÒ §[,

Code that seems to generate strange characters (as seen in SQLite Administrator):

```
...
// Constructor in Class
public ProfileUserAssignment()
{
    ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    _IsNew = true;

    SetDefaults();
}
...

...
// Save Method in same class
public ProfileUserAssignment Save()
{
    if (_IsNew)
    {
        Made4Print.SQLite.Repository.Add(this);
    }
    else
    {
        Made4Print.SQLite.Repository.Update(this);
    }

    return Get(this.ID);
}
...
```

Code that saves Guids as expected:

```
// Create Administrator User
using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection connection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(Made4Print.SQLite.GetProvider().ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
        sqlQuery.Append("INSERT INTO [Users] ( ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[ID], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[FirstName], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[LastName], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[Username], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[Password], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[Email], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[Phone], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[MobilePhone], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[LoginEnabledPropertyValue], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[SendEmailsPropertyValue], ");
        sqlQuery.Append("[SystemPropertyValue] ");
        sqlQuery.Append(" ) VALUES ( ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'2bdcac4d-019f-4213-b635-86ae8f7d757e', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'Administrator', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'User', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'xxxxx', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'" + Security.HashPassword("xxxxx") + "', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("'', ");
        sqlQuery.Append("1, ");
        sqlQuery.Append("1, ");
        sqlQuery.Append("1 ");
        sqlQuery.Append(" ) ");
        sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery.ToString();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Using SQLite Administrator, I see both the Guids as expected in one table or the characters in another table (havent tried doing both in on one table)

**NEW INFO FOUND:**

I just found this at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

Store GUID as text
Normally, GUIDs are stored in a binary format. Use this connection string to store GUIDs as text.

Data Source=filename;Version=3;BinaryGUID=False;

**Any comments on this?**

Comment: I am using ID = Guid.NewGuid() in the constructor, I assume its trying to save the Guid object rather than the Guid string value? if that makes sense?

Comment: What is the code snippet of the call? In the code version can you call Guid.NewGuid().ToString() instead?

Comment: Please show us the code involved, and the text "Using SQLite Administrator, I see both the Guids as expected or the characters?", is that a question or do you actually see it as expected?

Comment: @GrayWizardx: Added some code, I could use strings as IDs, havent considered that just yet.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen : No, its a statement, I see both.

Comment: Your guids are probably ok, it is the viewer software's problem-I also see this problem with firefox's sqlite manager. Using the server explorer in visual studio, and the System.Data.SQLite provider, the guids should look correct. System.Data.SQLite does the formatting magic for you.

Comment: @ P a u l: I have been adjusting so much stuff now and fixing small bugs in the classes that you may be correct that eveything might been ok from the start :-) I am using string ID's now though and contemplating changeing everything back, but its such a small app that I might just leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I will need to change IDs to strings instead of Guids.

I already seem to have to do this for bools, but doing this just to wrap IDs would be pointless:

```
public int LoginEnabledPropertyValue { get; set; }

[SubSonicIgnore]
public bool LoginEnabled
{
     get
     {
          return (LoginEnabledPropertyValue > 0 ? true : false);
     }
     set
     {
          LoginEnabledPropertyValue = (value ? 1 : 0);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I am using string IDs until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have the notion of "types" from what I've read so my first guess is that it's translating the value to a string, and your encoding it making it crazy. So, first question: what is the default encoding on your DB and default encoding on your machine?

Next - is it not working? Sometimes it's a good idea to enjoy the sausage without asking to see the kitchen. In this case SQLite is doing something funky, but if it returns the values OK then one might suggest you shouldn't be looking at them :).

Comment: I guess you're right, it's not translating something correctly, Everything is pretty much default, out the box. Pretty new to Sqlite, Subsonic and the .net wrapper.  Unfortunateky a select query to retrieve the expected record does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If using GUIDs without BinaryGUID=False; flag you have to build queries using AddWithValue method, 
I am doing it like this:

```
string SQL = "select count(*) from Groups where ID = @id";

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", groupId);

cmd.Connection = sql_con;

var ret = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```